# Synchron Ajax Call - or: How to wait until everything is loaded to go on?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a single page application with ASP.Net and JavaScipt / jQuery.

In my Page initialisation there is much to load, e.g. 6 dropdowns, a bunch of textboxfilles, configuration files etc.

Now I have a gridview to load. The problem ist, that the gridview needs data from the textboxes and dropdowns.

So how to know, when the asynchron ajax calls of everything else is finished?

Simply put a settimeout() for the loading grid and wait a bunch of time, e.g. 300ms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use callback function which will get called when response of ajax request arrives.

```
$.ajax({
    type:"method_type",
    url: "your_url",
    dataType: "data_type",
    async: true,
    success: function(data){
        callback(data);
    }
});

function callback(d){
  // grid functionality
}
```

Update:

```
$.when($.ajax("req1"), $.ajax("req2"))
  .then( callback, errfun);
```

This will execute the function `callback` when both ajax requests are successful, or `errfun` if either one has an error.

Comment: I know that but in fact, how to do that for a bunch of dipendencies? I need data for the grid from around 4 different ajax calls that are made before. not one

Comment: Wow that seems very nice! So in fact, that is a good method to ask for different ajax requests to finish? Can u explain your update a bit further, maybe make a example with 3 ajax calls so I understand the syntax and use of the methods

Answer (score 0):

There should be a `success` callback. In asynchronous programming, you stick event-driven code inside callback functions.

Comment: see above: I know that but in fact, how to do that for a bunch of dipendencies? I need data for the grid from around 4 different ajax calls that are made before. not one